# How to update a single item in a Sitecore index?

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

In my **Sitecore** content tree there are few thousands of items, and I just want to alter few items programmatically. Instead of rebuilding the entire lucene index which is taking a big time, I want to update index entries for each item I'm altering in real time. I tried

```cs
item.Database.Indexes.UpdateItem(item);
```

but it is obsolete and ask me to use `SearchManager`.

Can anyone guide me how to update index entries for a given item?

PS: I'm altering items from desktop application, not the website.

Comment: Aren't the entries in the index automatically updated after you change the Sitecore items programmatically?

Comment: I'm altering items from a desktop application, so I have to explicitly update the indexes. In the website it updates indexes automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to execute one of the `HistoryEngine.RegisterItem...` methods, e.g:

```
item.Database.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemSaved(item, new ItemChanges(item));
item.Database.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemCreated(item);
item.Database.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemMoved(item, oldParentId);
```

Comment: Hi Maras,

I tried with your given statements, but the index did not got updated. And my requirement is not to register entries, but to update the index in real time.

Comment: Hi Maras, previously I have tried only the RegisterItemCreated() method since I'm creating fresh items and it didn't work. Now I have used the three given statements as it is after I'm creating the item and do any changes to it, and now the index is updating. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well actually there is no Update operation on indexes, so feel free to do delete/add